# twilio sms api - is my sms delivered or NOT-delivered to end user?

Tags: php, callback, twilio

I use twilio API to send SMS from my php application. When the 'to' number is malformed (invalid area code, invalid digits number etc) twilio works fine, giving me an exception.

My problem is when I try to send to a number that is in good format, however it doesn't exist. It show it as 'sent' and no exception is given. I also tried the callback option:

```
array('StatusCallback' => 'http://uncurler.heroku.com/v1/<some code >').
```

Even when i view the report here it shows as 'sent'.

Is there a way to actually know if the message was delivered? Or more importantly if it was NOT delivered? If not, is it possible from some other API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

So currently the Status value does not reflect anything beyond our ability to deliver the message to the carrier.  It does not reflect any information about whether or not the carrier was able to deliver the message or not.

If the carrier accepts the message from us, we mark the message as Sent.

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks Devin, it does. I suggest you put this clearly in your documentation, because you have all these different possible statuses, but actually only 'sent' is possible.